# How to set up custom user actions in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I am a first timer at Firebase Analytics and I need some help with event logging.

I'd like to organize my user actions like "Screen X, event Y".

What I achieved so far is this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, screenName);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, actionName);
firebase.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

and I invoke this method every time I want to log something.

In the Analytics console, this translates to a chart with all the screen names organized by `Content_type`, like this:

[image]

but when I click on one of the items (the tutorial screen "TUT" for example), nothing is organized by `actionName`. It's all bundled in (`not_set`) like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to handle this type of stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

It seems like you need to set an `ITEM_ID` as well, in addition to `CONTENT_TYPE` and `ITEM_NAME`.

Hence I got it working by just adding the `ITEM_ID` parameter like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, screenName);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, actionName);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, actionName);
firebase.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I don't know if it is the right way to handle this kind of event logging but it works for now.

Better solutions are welcome!!